# VLookup Range Change when shifting and deleting columns in the range of the Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following search function:

```
=ALS((VERT.ZOEKEN(B6;'Raw Data'!$H$1:$BB$3000;21;ONWAAR))=100;"Winkel";
ALS((VERT.ZOEKEN(B6;'Raw Data'!$H$1:$BB$3000;21;ONWAAR))=400;"Woning";
ALS((VERT.ZOEKEN(B6;'Raw Data'!$H$1:$BB$3000;21;ONWAAR))=500;"Parkeerplaats";
ALS((VERT.ZOEKEN(B6;'Raw Data'!$H$1:$BB$3000;21;ONWAAR))=200;"Kantoor";
ALS((VERT.ZOEKEN(B6;'Raw Data'!$H$1:$BB$3000;21;ONWAAR))=600;
"Antenne";"Overig")))))
```

But when I change and delete some of the columns in the range of the Vlookup search with a macro (Vert.Zoeken=Dutch for Vlookup) The Range specified within the formula changes.

Why does it do that, and how do i stop it? I Couldn't find a clear answer anywhere else.

(The macro code just deletes some columns, and doesn't do anything else really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cell ID vs Cell Location**

One of Excel's primary mechanics is that each cell effectively has its own "ID", which is represented by that the location of that cell at the time that it was referenced. The location of that cell can change, when columns & rows are manipulated.

For example: in A1, make the formula

```
=B5+D3
```

Then insert a row above row 3, and a column to the left of B. Your formula will now read:

```
=C6+E3
```

You'll notice that because the locations of the unique cells was changed, the formula accounted for that. This feature is incredibly useful, as otherwise, even simply formulas would need to be completely re-written if a new header was inserted above some numbers.

If you want the position of a reference to be "absolute" in the sense that it always points to the same *location* instead of the same *cell ID*, then you have a few options:

**VBA solution to ignore this feature**

By its nature, VBA code does not automatically adjust when cell references change. If you have a formula which references Range("B5"), then it will still say Range("B5") after you insert a new column to the left of B. In this way, you could use VBA to build the formulas within your worksheet. ie: VBA could re-write the formulas to reference the columns you want it to.

**Excel solution to ignore this feature**

To solve this without VBA, meaning your VBA code would not need to re-write the formulas, you could use the INDIRECT function. INDIRECT allows you to dynamically determine what a cell reference is, based on building a text string of a location. For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT("B"&5+10&":D100"),2,0)
```

This will create the text string "B15:D100", and that will be the range referenced by VLOOKUP. Because you have entered the "B" & "D" as text values, they will not change when you insert rows/columns.

Comment: Note that INDIRECT is an expensive function; it re-runs whenever a workbook updates, because Excel can't automatically tell what its precedents are. I advise you generally to rebuild your workbook dynamically, and take advantage of the benefits of Excel's automatic reference adjustments, if possible. Otherwise, VBA may be the cleanest solution since you are using it already.